# Unable to open or view htaccess and other hidden files in Mac

Tags: macos, .htaccess

I'm using Mac OS X Lion and I can't open any htaccess files or view them in finder. I'd like to be able to view hidden files, so I tried `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` followed by `killall Finder` but that did nothing.

I logged in as the root user. Then I tried `open /path/to/.htaccess` but it wouldn't open. It gave me a message like

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.htaccess: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.htaccess: line 1: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>'
logout

[Process completed]
```

With text wangler I can see any hidden files, but they're grayed out and I can't select them. The only way I've been able to open any htaccess (or other hidden files) is with `vi open /path/to/file`. I opened it with vi, but there are no newlines or blank spaces at all.

Comment: This is seemingly not a programming question, but instead a user question, which more likely belongs on either ServerFault, SuperUser, or AskDifferent (all Stack Exchange sites, but with the purposes of answering Server questions, power user questions, or Macintosh questions).  In this case, `open` will open the file using the default program, not using an editor.  You will need to use the `-a` flag to explicitly give an application to open the file (`man open` for more information).

Comment: A few tips: Hidden files are visible from the terminal with ls -a, 
you may have more luck with nano, and files can be opened as root via sudo nano /foo/bar